# Is there any research on the detection of the user's emotion and stress based on the mouse movement and keyboard?

Tags: reference-request, emotional-intelligence, affective-computing, emotion-recognition

I have to create a model that can detect the user's emotion and stress level based on their mouse movement and keyboard typing activity. I didn't found any research work based on this. Is there any research on this?

Comment: A quick [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=mouse+movement+stress&btnG=) gives me plenty of literature on this topic. Maybe your question can be more specific so we know what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mafu Feel free to provide an answer below with links to some reliable and potentially useful research papers (maybe briefly describe their approach, although this was not required in the question). Maybe the user was not aware of Google Scholar. If you think this question is unclear or needs more details, you should flag it as such. See also https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down.